# Find the index position of the first non-NA value in an R vector?

Tags: r

I have a problem where a vector has a bunch of NAs at the beginning, and data thereafter. However the peculiarity of my data is that the first n values that are non NA, are probably unreliable, so I would like to remove them and replace them with NA.

For example, if I have a vector of length 20, and non-NAs start at index position 4:

```
> z
 [1]          NA          NA          NA -1.64801942 -0.57209233  0.65137286  0.13324344 -2.28339326
 [9]  1.29968050  0.10420776  0.54140323  0.64418164 -1.00949072 -1.16504423  1.33588892  1.63253646
[17]  2.41181291  0.38499825 -0.04869589  0.04798073
```

I would like to remove the first 3 non-NA values, which I believe to be unreliable, to give this:

```
> z
 [1]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA  0.13324344 -2.28339326
 [9]  1.29968050  0.10420776  0.54140323  0.64418164 -1.00949072 -1.16504423  1.33588892  1.63253646
[17]  2.41181291  0.38499825 -0.04869589  0.04798073
```

Of course I need a general solution and I never know when the first non-NA value starts. How would I go about doing this? IE how do I find out the index position of the first non-NA value?

For completeness, my data is actually arranged in a data frame with lots of these vectors in columns, and each vector can have a different non-NA starting position. Also once the data starts, there may be sporadic NAs further down, which prevents me from simply counting their number, as a solution.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to do this that stops searching when it finds the first one?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use a combination of `is.na` and `which` to find the non-NA index locations.

```
NonNAindex <- which(!is.na(z))
firstNonNA <- min(NonNAindex)

# set the next 3 observations to NA
is.na(z) <- seq(firstNonNA, length.out=3)
```

Comment: Dang, this was my second guess. Wanted to be fancy with `rle()` but I like this solution better.

Comment: Perfect thanks. After some thought I came up with
min((1:length(z))[!is.na(z)]), but of course this which idea is much better. Perfect

Comment: Is `firstNonNA <- NonNAindex[1]` faster?  Would I run into some problem with using `[1]` vs. `min()`?

Comment: @FlorianJenn: yes, that would likely be faster, especially for larger vectors. I can't immediately think of a problem of using it over `min`.

Comment: For those who just want to remove all NAs (a bit different from what this question is asking): `x <- c(NA, "B", "C", "D"); x[!is.na(x)]`

Answer (score 28):

Similar idea to that of @Joshua, but using `which.min()`

```
## dummy data
set.seed(1)
dat <- runif(10)
dat[seq_len(sample(10, 1))] <- NA

## start of data
start <- which.min(is.na(dat))
```

which gives:

```
> (start <- which.min(is.na(dat)))
[1] 4
```

Use this to set `start:(start+2)` to `NA`

```
is.na(dat) <- seq(start, length.out = 3)
```

resulting in:

```
> dat
 [1]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
 [6]         NA 0.94467527 0.66079779 0.62911404 0.06178627
```

Comment: even cleaner. Thanks, and also for the continuation of the answer.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure about cleaner. It's shorter but may be less clear to people who don't realize `which.min` coerces `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0`, respectively.

Comment: @Joshua agreed, it also relies on the behaviour that which.min returns the first of any tied minima. Not sure shorter deserves the accept.

Comment: This one seems to struggle with instances where NAs are followed by non-NAs and than you have NAs here and there. The index returned is not applicable. The solution detailed by Joshua works as expected.

Comment: @MatteoCastagna This works for the OPs example and Q, where `NA`s are at the front of the vector. As I mention in the comments, this relies on behaviour of `which.min()`, which is exactly the reason for it failing in the situation you describe.

Answer (score 17):

If dealing with large data, `Position` is considerably faster than `which`, because it only evaluates until a match is found, rather than evaluating the whole vector.

```
x=c(rep(NA,3),1:1e8)
Position(function(x) !is.na(x), x)
# 4
```

We can assign NA to the following N values (or the end of the vector, whichever comes first) by

```
pos = Position(function(x)!is.na(x), x)
x[pos:min(pos+N-1, length(x))] <- NA
```

Comment: This performs well on large data

Comment: no need to define a new function, you can use `complete.cases`

Answer (score 2):

I would do it something along the lines of

```
# generate some data
tb <- runif(10)
tb[1:3] <- NA

# I convert vector to TRUE/FALSE based on whether it's NA or not
# rle function will tell you when something "changes" in the vector
# (in our case from TRUE to FALSE)
tb.rle <- rle(is.na(tb))

# this is where vector goes from all TRUE to (at least one) FALSE
# your first true number is one position ahead, so +1
tb.rle$lengths[1] 

# you can now subset your vector with the first non-NA value
# and do with it whatever you want. I assign it a fantastic 
# non-believable number
tb[tb.rle$lengths[1] + 1] <- 42
```

Answer (score 2):

na.trim() in the zoo package can help.

```
library(zoo)
dummy.data <- c(rep(NA, 5), seq(1:7), NA)
x <- length(dummy.data) - length(na.trim(dummy.data, sides = "left"))
dummy.data[(x+1):(x+3)] <- NA
dummy.data
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4  5  6  7 NA
```

Answer (score -2):

You can directly use replace() function also, I know answer is already there but like replace() is too good with these kind of things

For Example-:

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,58,NA,98,NA,NA,NA)
which(is.na(A))
A <- replace(A,1:3,NA)
```