# identifying rows following specifc row based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe/tibble containing yearly observations of several countries. In years in which a specific event happens the variable `event` gets the value 1.

I am now trying to specify a new column `event.10yrs` which gets the value 1 for the 9 years following the end of an event (= last year of the event if event lasts several years). In years in which a new event occurs and which are not the last year of the new event, the new column `event.10yrs` gets the value 0.

Below the data for one single country. Column `event.10yrs` is the desired output.

```
 df <-structure(list(year = c(1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 
1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 
1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), ccode = c(516, 516, 516, 
516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 
516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 
516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 516, 
516, 516, 516, 516), event = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), event.last.y = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), event.10yrs = c(NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), vars = "ccode", drop = TRUE, class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), indices = list(0:45), group_sizes = 46L, biggest_group_size = 46L, labels = structure(list(
    ccode = 516), row.names = c(NA, -1L), vars = "ccode", drop = TRUE, class = "data.frame", .Names = "ccode"), .Names = c("year", 
"ccode", "event", "event.last.y", "event.10yrs"))
```

My attempt so far using the dplyr package:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(event.10yrs=case_when(event!=1 & year-9 < year[event.last.y==1] ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ 0))
```

This, however, renders the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In year < year[rs.war.last.y == 1] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Grateful for any hint.

Comment: how do you know there is a new event or when it' ends ?

Comment: @JulienNavarre colum event is 1 when an event occurs; column event.last.y identifies the last year of the event.

Comment: so why 1970 is `NA` and 1971 `0` ?

Comment: @JulienNavarre 1970 must be an error, should be 0 as well; in 1970 there was no event (hence 0). years of interest however only start with 1972 (up to 1981); then again 1998 (up to 1999); 2003 (up to 2010). many thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just a nested ifelse (or dplyr::if_else)

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ev_10 = if_else(event == 0, 1, 
                           if_else(event.last.y ==1, 1, 0), 
                                                           0))
```

**edit**

this post helped me here : [Find the index position of the first non-NA value in an R vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808621/find-the-index-position-of-the-first-non-na-value-in-an-r-vector)

But we want to replace not only for the first occurrence of 'x' ...
so I made a little workaround with a helper column

```
index_1 <- unlist(lapply(which(df$event.last.y ==1 ), 
           function(x) seq(x, length.out=9))) 
# this makes a vector with all the index of the last 9 positions 
# after the last value == 1 
df$last_code <- df$event.last.y #just to duplicate your column
df$last_code[index_1] <- 1 #replacing the indices with '1'
```

Now we can use the simple nested conditional statement as before

```
df <- df %>% mutate(ev_10 = if_else(event == 0 & last_code==1, 1, 
#added the condition that last_code needs to be '1'
                          if_else(event.last.y ==1, 1, 0), 
                          0))

 head(df[c(2:13, 31:40),], 20) #printing only example rows here
# A tibble: 20 x 7
# Groups:   ccode [1]
    year ccode event event.last.y event.10yrs last_code ev_10
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1971   516  0            0           0         0     0   
 2  1972   516  1.00         1.00        1.00      1.00  1.00
 3  1973   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
 4  1974   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
 5  1975   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
 6  1976   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
 7  1977   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
 8  1978   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
 9  1979   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
10  1980   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
11  1981   516  0            0           1.00      0     0   
12  1982   516  0            0           0         0     0  
... 
13  2000   516  1.00         0           0         1.00  0   
14  2001   516  1.00         0           0         1.00  0   
15  2002   516  1.00         0           0         1.00  0   
16  2003   516  1.00         1.00        1.00      1.00  1.00
17  2004   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
18  2005   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
19  2006   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
20  2007   516  0            0           1.00      1.00  1.00
```

Comment: many thanks!  the new variable (ev_10 in your exaple) should get the value 1 only for the 9 years following the the event; not all the way until a new event occurs (at max; if a new event occurs before 9 years, ev_10 gets the value 1 for less than 9 years).

Comment: just saw, it does not entirely correspond to your requested result - maybe I misunderstood what you meant with the last 9 years after the event.. You might want to change the `length.out` argument in the `which` call